# Type mismatch: cannot convert from View to ImageView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image, imageview

I can not understand why this error appears. Can someone help me ?

Here is my code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {
ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

    iv = (ImageView)findViewById (R.id.imageView1);
```

Comment: I would start by cleaning and rebuilding your project. Assuming that `imageView1` is an `ImageView` in`activity_main_activity2.xml`

Comment: please post your log cat error and your xml file.

Comment: This error occurs in two cases, 1) You don't have ImageView1 in your xml 2) you have missed ">" in your xml file. So, it is better to check your xml.

Comment: @ErAcube not really. In your first case, it would through a NPE. In the second, it wouldn't compile. With Eclipse, it happens often when changing xml files. A clean and rebuild typically fixes the problem.

Comment: i already clean and rebuild but still the same, n i also change the id imageView1 to other name, the error still appear

Comment: @user4668241 please post your xml file and logcat

Comment: its ok. the error has gone. thanks guyss

Answer (score 0):

You should verify some topics here:

- You really have an ImageView in your layout
- Is the ID of your ImageView @+id/imageView1 in your layout ?
- Did you made a typo when declaring your ImageView in layout xml ?

Comment: thanks for your answer. my problem have solved by rename the id

Comment: So probably you already has an imageView1 in your project anywhere. You may avoid those issues, giving unique names for your objects. Try to be more specific, like: (@+id/main_view_imageView). This way, you will garantee that you won't use the same ID  and will be easier to use =D